# <!DOCTYPE html> не даёт работать JS

Tags: javascript

С `<!DOCTYPE html>` не  работает эта функция ;  работает только с xhtml либо без `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста

```
 function resize() {
    document.getElementById("Img").style.height = (document.body.clientHeight - 100 ) * 0.9 ;
  }
```

Comment: `clientHeight` у вас видимо ноль. Если вы хотите узнать высоту окна браузера, используйте другие способы, например `document.documentElement.clientHeight` или `window.innerHeight`

Comment: то же самое , без Doctype работает , а с - нет

Comment: Тогда остаётся попросить [mcve], потому что непонятно, как не работает